# How to work around "Object Already Exists" Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a query with a different range of data but for some reason when I run it, it gives back an error stating:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 54
>   There is already an object named '##contacts' in the database.

How would I get around this? Is it a column or columns in the database that are created and that I need to drop?

Code I'm using:

```sql
use KBData
go

declare 
    @startdate datetime='2010-01-01',
    @enddate datetime = '2020-05-26';

/*from contacts*/
select
    lower(c.contactid) as contactid ,
    replace(replace(lower(c.emailaddress1),' ',''),',','') as emailaddress1,
    replace(replace(lower(c.emailaddress2),' ',''),',','') as emailaddress2,
    replace(replace(lower(c.emailaddress3),' ',''),',','') as emailaddress3
into ##contacts
from crm.Contact c
where (c.createdonutc >= @startdate and c.createdonutc < dateadd(dd,1,@enddate))
and (c.emailaddress1 is not null or c.emailaddress2 is not null or c.emailaddress3 is not null)

/*from buyers*/
select 
    lower(b.Email) as email
into #sales
from crm.SalesAgreement s  
left join dbo.BuyerContracts bc
    join dbo.buyers b
    on b.ProspectNo = bc.ProspectNo
    and b.Deleted is null  
    on s.kb_salesagreementnumber = bc.SalesAgreementNo
    and bc.Deleted is null
where (s.kb_saledate >= @startdate and s.kb_saledate < dateadd(dd,1,@enddate))
and s.Deleted is null   ;

select
    distinct replace(replace(lower(b.email),' ',''),',','') as email
into #buyers
from #sales b
where b.Email is not null ;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using the global `##contacts` instead of the local `#contacts`? If there is, have you dropped the `##contacts` created last time you run this code?

Comment: No reason, just the way I had seen from looking up things online. Is it more efficient to use #contacts? I did not drop it, i just figured I can keep rewriting it but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're running into stems from your use of a global temporary table (`##tableName`) rather than a local temporary table (`#tableName`). The two behave differently.

A local temp table is created on the fly, is only accessible from the session where it is created, and is dropped when that session closes it's connection, or unless it is explicitly dropped before that. It's completely contained within that scope.

A global temp table is also created on the fly, but is then accessible via any connection to the server. For instance (and I was just doing this earlier today), you can create a global temp table in one SSMS window, and then work with that table in multiple other SSMS windows. Or someone else from your team can work with it. The table continues to exist until the last session accessing the table is disconnected, or, also, unless it's explicitly dropped before then.

So if you had two sessions open with this code running, the `##contacts` from one session would already exist when the second session tries to create it. There are a few situations when you *need* a global temp table, and you need to do existence checks and such in those sitations, but they're few and far between. It's generally easier to work with local temp tables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can I keep writing to it though once it's been created? Once I've created it as a local temporary table, it won't let me run to it again. For example I messed up on my dates and wasn't able to run it again. Do I have to just keep reconnecting to reset the session when this happens? There's no way to just keep re-writing to the object?

Comment: When you use `SELECT...INTO` to write to a table, temp or otherwise, under the hood the SQL engine generates a `CREATE TABLE` statement. So you can only `SELECT...INTO` once. Typically, I issue explicit `CREATE TABLE` statements myself, then do `INSERT INTO` in my subsequent code. Little more typing up front, but easier to maintain, I think, anyway.